# Синхронизация потоков, различия

Tags: c#, .net, clr

В чем различие между:

- lock (someobject) {}
- Использование Mutex
- Использование семафора
- Использование монитора
- Класс AutoResetEvent
- ReaderWriterLock

Comment: @AzizUmarov да норм вопрос. Возникла ситуация когда нужно синхронизировать например, а фреймворк тебе для этого предлагает 100500 инструментов, какой использовать - не понятно. Эталонный разбор этой темы  не помешал бы (если такого еще нет)

Comment: На эту тему написаны целые книги. Лучше почитайте документацию и, если по ней возникнут вопросы, задайте их здесь.

Comment: В дополнение к перечисленным можно накидать ещё дюжину классов, так или иначе связанных с синхронизацией. С трудом представляю, как в одном довольно коротком сообщении увязать их всех и внятно что-либо объяснить. Хотя попытаться можно...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я знаю что есть еще другие классы которые связаны с синхроном потоков , но эти самые частые , конечно мне полный ответ не нужен , скорее всего я его полностью не пойму (еще новичок ) мне бы хотелось узнать когда что использовать .

Comment: Собственно напрямую монитор обычно не используют. У `lock` внутри на самом деле монитор и есть, но так его гораздо удобнее использовать. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Interlocked` - если нужно атомарно изменить значение одной простой переменной.

`lock` - если нужно изменять сложные (составные) типы или множество простых.

`Mutex` - используется для межпроцессной коммуникации (в отличие от межпоточной).

`Semaphore(Slim)` - если нужно ограничить количество потоков, работающих одновременно с ресурсом.

`ReaderWriterLock(Slim)` - реализует стандартный паттерн "Один писатель - много читателей". Судя по многочисленны отзывам, страдает плохой производительностью, даже версия Slim. Устарел. В некоторых случаях его можно заменить на Task + pipeline.

Потокобезопасные коллекции из `System.Collections.Concurrent` - для безопасной работы с коллекциями объектов из нескольких потоков.

Кардинальное решение проблемы - переход на иммутабельные (неизменяемые) типы. В частности, коллекции `System.Collections.Immutable`. Нет разделяемых ресурсов - не нужна синхронизация.

Comment: Можно добавить Concurrent коллекции ещё )

Comment: @CrazyElf - я сделал ответ общим, чтобы любой желающий мог дополнять.

Comment: @CrazyElf - у меня мысли разбегаются: и про Concurrent написать, и про Immutable collections, и про примитивы Spin*, и многое другое.

Comment: Даже не знал про такую фичу как "общий ответ". Вписал коллекции на пробу )

Comment: Task + pipeline не замена ReaderWriterLock-у. Они решают разные задачи